# How to make fractal-like bubbling pattern with spheres?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, particles, procedural

For a graphic design project, I want to illustrate a fractal-Style arrangement of “bubbling” spheres: a network of “hub spheres” with smaller spheres that each have their own hub, smaller and smaller, etc. Here is a sketch of what I mean:
[image]

Is there a way to make this semi-random, fractal dispersion of spheres in Blender (2.8)?